# What to write in "Web location" field when starting an "New website" in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I want a website to be deployed automatically to a local IIS (built in Windows XP Pro SP3), avoiding VisualStudio-built-in server if possible. I'd like development source files to be stored in a project folder outside wwwroot (I wouldn't mind built files to be copied to wwwroot each time I press F5).

I don't store my projects inside default directories inside "My documents". What should I specify as in "Web location" when starting an "New website" in Visual Studio 2010? A deployment path in wwwroot, a folder where I'd like to save my project, or something else?

I want the website to be a part of a complex solution in VS 2010, also icludinc a class libray project, a WinForms application project, a Windows Service project and a common Entitity Framework data model.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Publish option in the Build menu to deploy your files to the actual IIS Server, wherever that is located.  Undoubtedly you feel that you have strong reasons for doing it the way you described, but:

1. There is no practical way to install a current version of IIS on Windows XP
2. Putting development files directly into the wwwroot directory of an IIS Server makes me nervous
3. The web server that comes with Visual Studio is good enough for development, and is designed specifically for that purpose.

Comment: "The web server that comes with Visual Studio is good enough for development, and is designed specifically for that purpose."  

1. It works many times slower and consumes more memory than normal IIS. After it has fallen into no-response with 90% CPU load for a long time on a very basic application (full-scaffold Dynamic Data Entities application, 33 very-very simple tables, no data yet, no load) once, I've considered giving up using it.

2. Sometimes I just use some of my web applications and don't want to wait while Visual Studio loads.

XP-SP3-bundled IIS works perfectly with VS 2010.

Comment: Well, you're going to need to stand up a Windows 2008 Server for testing, if you want to do it right.

Comment: My oldy laptop will probably blow up then :-|